# If today = date_in_cell (or iteration of today + X) - Google Apps / Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, date, if-statement, google-apps

I want to send email reminders every X days (after the date in cell) until user changes status in row.

Once-off date conditions are easy EG:

```
If date = today OR date = today + 2 OR date = today + 4
```

On my "settings" sheet I have a "frequency" setting where the number of days between email reminders are set.

Is it possible to put a loop within an if statement?  EG:

```
If today = date_in_cell OR today = date_in_cell + any multiple of X
```

IE - Date in cell is Monday.  I want an email on Wednesday, Friday, Sunday, Tuesday, Thursday, ETC (forever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the remainder operator (`%`). You calculate the difference in days between the start date and today, then if that's greater than 0 and that number `%` the number of days is 0, it's a day you need to send a reminder:

```
var elapsed = Math.floor((today - dt) / ONE_DAY_IN_MS);
var sendEmail = elapsed > 0 && elapsed % days == 0;
```

Live Example:

```js
var ONE_DAY_IN_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // Defined by the spec
function format(dt) {
  var rv = [dt.getFullYear()];
  var n = dt.getMonth()  + 1;
  rv.push(n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
  var n = dt.getDate();
  rv.push(n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
  return rv.join("-");
}
function test(dt, today, days) {
  var elapsed = Math.floor((today - dt) / ONE_DAY_IN_MS);
  var sendEmail = elapsed > 0 && elapsed % days == 0;
  console.log(format(dt), format(today), sendEmail ? "Yes" : "No");
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.clear();
  var dt = new Date(2018, 0, 1); // Jan 1st
  var today = new Date(2018, 0, 1); // Jan 1st
  var days = +document.getElementById("days").value;
  for (var n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    test(dt, today, days);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="days" value="2">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show">
```